# Logstash logdate type issue

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I want to log 'logdate' as type date but even after applying date filter i am getting the 'logdate' type as string. Here is my filter :

```
filter {
    grok {
         match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate}\s%{LOGLEVEL:level} +: +%{WORD:USE_CASE} +: +%{WORD:STEP_DETAIL} +: +\[%{WORD:CIN}\] +: +(?<MID>([^\s]+)) +: +%{GREEDYDATA:MESSAGE_DETAILS}" }
         add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
         add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
         add_tag => [ "level:%{level}" ]
         add_tag => [ "USE_CASE:%{USE_CASE}" ]
         add_tag => [ "CIN:%{CIN}" ]
         add_tag => [ "MID-%{MID}" ]  
        }
    date {
        match => [ "logdate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
           target => "@timestamp"
      }
    }
```

and here is the mapping which i get after hitting the command

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_mapping?pretty
```

Mapping :

```
  "logdate" : {
    "type" : "string",
    "norms" : {
      "enabled" : false
    },
    "fields" : {
      "raw" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed",
        "ignore_above" : 256
      }
    }
  },
```

where i am doing wrong ? any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `logdate` field to be a date field, you need to make it the `target` of the `date` filter

```
date {
   match => [ "logdate", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
   target => "logdate"
}
```

This won't set `@timestamp` to the same thing, so you may want to do it again to set `@timestamp`.